# How to use systemd for starting endless log generating commands

Tags: command-line, services, systemd

I'm using some Apache projects like Apache Kafka and Apache Zookeeper. The difference between two is that when I issue Apache Kafka command on the terminal,`kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.conf` it generates logs and did not give back the control of the command line (the new line that I can issue some other command). But issuing the zookeeper service after some line logging, it gives back the terminal command to me.

Now I created services for Kafka and Zookeeper to start at the boot time automatically. The following is the template for `*.service` files:

```
[Unit]
Description=Zookeeper Daemon
Wants=syslog.target

[Service]    
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/home/zookeeper
User=zookeeper 
ExecStart=/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start
TimeoutSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `.service` file for both Kafka and Zookeeper have the same structure.

Starting Zookeeper service at the booting time is ok but the problem is when the command for starting Kafka service is issued, as Kafka run command structure does not back the command to the user, the `systemd` consider it as unsuccessful start and after a timeout, label it as a failed or inactive service! Does `systemd` have a solution for running such commands as a service?

**Update1:** using `ExecStart="/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties &"` it errors:

```
kafka.service - Kafka Daemon


Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kafka.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-12-16 14:20:00 IRST; 3h 29min left
  Process: 925 ExecStart=/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties & (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Dec 16 14:19:58 kafka1 systemd[1]: Starting Kafka Daemon...
Dec 16 14:20:00 kafka1 systemd[1]: kafka.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Dec 16 14:20:00 kafka1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Kafka Daemon.
Dec 16 14:20:00 kafka1 systemd[1]: kafka.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 16 14:20:00 kafka1 systemd[1]: kafka.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

.

**Update2:** The `sudo journalctl -xe` output is:

```
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit rc-local.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: initializing GeoIP Country (IPv4) (type 1) DB
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 iscsid[1180]: iSCSI logger with pid=1186 started!
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: iscsid.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/iscsid.pid: Invalid argument
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started iSCSI initiator daemon (iscsid).
-- Subject: Unit iscsid.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit iscsid.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Starting Login to default iSCSI targets...
-- Subject: Unit open-iscsi.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit open-iscsi.service has begun starting up.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: GEO-106FREE 20160408 Bu
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: initializing GeoIP Country (IPv6) (type 12) DB
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: GEO-106FREE 20160408 Bu
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: GeoIP City (IPv4) (type 2) DB not available
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: GeoIP City (IPv4) (type 6) DB not available
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: GeoIP City (IPv6) (type 30) DB not available
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: GeoIP City (IPv6) (type 31) DB not available
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: GeoIP Region (type 3) DB not available
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: GeoIP Region (type 7) DB not available
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: GeoIP ISP (type 4) DB not available
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: GeoIP Org (type 5) DB not available
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: GeoIP AS (type 9) DB not available
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: GeoIP Domain (type 11) DB not available
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: GeoIP NetSpeed (type 10) DB not available
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [32768, 60999]
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [32768, 60999]
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: listening on IPv6 interfaces, port 53
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: listening on IPv4 interface enp0s17, 192.168.1.201#53
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: generating session key for dynamic DNS
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: sizing zone task pool based on 5 zones
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 iscsiadm[1193]: iscsiadm: No records found
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: using built-in root key for view _default
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: set up managed keys zone for view _default, file 'managed-keys.bind'
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: automatic empty zone: 10.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started Login to default iSCSI targets.
-- Subject: Unit open-iscsi.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd

Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: configuring command channel from '/etc/bind/rndc.key'
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: configuring command channel from '/etc/bind/rndc.key'
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: couldn't add command channel ::1#953: address not available
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand".
-- Subject: Unit ondemand.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit ondemand.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started Permit User Sessions.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-user-sessions.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-user-sessions.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
-- Subject: Unit plymouth-quit-wait.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit plymouth-quit-wait.service has begun starting up.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
-- Subject: Unit plymouth-quit.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit plymouth-quit.service has begun starting up.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
-- Subject: Unit plymouth-quit-wait.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit plymouth-quit-wait.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 apport[1205]:  * Starting automatic crash report generation: apport
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
-- Subject: Unit getty@tty1.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit getty@tty1.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
-- Subject: Unit getty.target has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit getty.target has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Starting Set console scheme...
-- Subject: Unit setvtrgb.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit setvtrgb.service has begun starting up.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.
-- Subject: Unit plymouth-quit.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit plymouth-quit.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 66
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 irqbalance[1209]:  * Starting SMP IRQ Balancer: irqbalance
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started LSB: VMware Tools thinprint.
-- Subject: Unit vmware-tools-thinprint.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit vmware-tools-thinprint.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: all zones loaded
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 named[1116]: running
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started Set console scheme.
-- Subject: Unit setvtrgb.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit setvtrgb.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 apport[1205]:    ...done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
-- Subject: Unit apport.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apport.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started LXD - container startup/shutdown.
-- Subject: Unit lxd-containers.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit lxd-containers.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 irqbalance[1209]:    ...done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems.
-- Subject: Unit irqbalance.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit irqbalance.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 ntp[1204]:  * Starting NTP server ntpd
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 ntpd[1272]: ntpd 4.2.8p4@1.3265-o Thu Sep  7 20:43:09 UTC 2017 (1): Starting
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 ntpd[1272]: Command line: /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 111:117
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 ntp[1204]:    ...done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start NTP daemon.
-- Subject: Unit ntp.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit ntp.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
-- Subject: Unit multi-user.target has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit multi-user.target has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
-- Subject: Unit graphical.target has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit graphical.target has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service has begun starting up.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 systemd[1]: Startup finished in 14.613s (kernel) + 9.707s (userspace) = 24.321s.
-- Subject: System start-up is now complete
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- All system services necessary queued for starting at boot have been
-- successfully started. Note that this does not mean that the machine is
-- now idle as services might still be busy with completing start-up.
-- 
-- Kernel start-up required 14613810 microseconds.
-- 
-- Initial RAM disk start-up required INITRD_USEC microseconds.
-- 
-- Userspace start-up required 9707956 microseconds.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: proto: precision = 0.089 usec (-23)
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Listen normally on 3 enp0s17 192.168.1.201:123
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Listening on routing socket on fd #20 for interface updates
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd[1028]: daemon.go:250: DEBUG: init done in 1.128521ms
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd[1028]: daemon.go:251: started snapd/2.25 (series 16; classic) ubuntu/16.04 (amd64) linux/4.4.0-87-generic.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 snapd[1028]: 2017/12/16 14:20:02.886275 daemon.go:251: started snapd/2.25 (series 16; classic) ubuntu/16.04 (amd64) linux/4.4.0-87-generic.
Dec 16 14:20:02 kafka1 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd[1028]: snapmgr.go:496: DEBUG: Next refresh scheduled for 2017-12-16 20:27:09.921506057 +0330 IRST.
Dec 16 14:20:03 kafka1 iscsid[1186]: iSCSI daemon with pid=1187 started!
Dec 16 14:20:03 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 194.225.50.25
Dec 16 14:20:04 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 5.144.132.2
Dec 16 14:20:04 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 5.144.132.2
Dec 16 14:20:05 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 82.99.215.101
Dec 16 14:20:05 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 5.79.108.34
Dec 16 14:20:06 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 95.46.198.21
Dec 16 14:20:06 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 82.99.215.102
Dec 16 14:20:06 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 212.51.144.44
Dec 16 14:20:07 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 72.5.72.15
Dec 16 14:20:07 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 131.155.140.129
Dec 16 14:20:08 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 195.78.244.50
Dec 16 14:20:08 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 213.136.0.252
Dec 16 14:20:09 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 195.141.190.190
Dec 16 14:20:09 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 2a02:c205:2009:8290::1
Dec 16 14:20:09 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 91.189.91.157
Dec 16 14:20:10 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 91.189.94.4
Dec 16 10:50:12 kafka1 systemd[1]: Time has been changed
-- Subject: Time change
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The system clock has been changed to REALTIME microseconds after January 1st, 1970.
Dec 16 10:50:13 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 194.225.150.25
Dec 16 10:50:13 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp from 131.155.140.129
Dec 16 10:50:13 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: Soliciting pool server 91.189.89.198
Dec 16 10:50:31 kafka1 sshd[1670]: Accepted password for kafka from 192.168.1.110 port 38698 ssh2
Dec 16 10:50:31 kafka1 sshd[1670]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user kafka by (uid=0)
Dec 16 10:50:31 kafka1 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of kafka.
-- Subject: Unit user-1001.slice has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user-1001.slice has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 10:50:31 kafka1 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1001...
-- Subject: Unit user@1001.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user@1001.service has begun starting up.
Dec 16 10:50:31 kafka1 systemd[1673]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user kafka by (uid=0)
Dec 16 10:50:31 kafka1 systemd-logind[936]: New session 1 of user kafka.
-- Subject: A new session 1 has been created for user kafka
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
-- 
-- A new session with the ID 1 has been created for the user kafka.
-- 
-- The leading process of the session is 1670.
Dec 16 10:50:31 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started Session 1 of user kafka.
-- Subject: Unit session-1.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-1.scope has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 10:50:31 kafka1 systemd[1673]: Reached target Paths.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 10:50:31 kafka1 systemd[1673]: Reached target Timers.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 10:50:31 kafka1 systemd[1673]: Reached target Sockets.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 10:50:31 kafka1 systemd[1673]: Reached target Basic System.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 10:50:31 kafka1 systemd[1673]: Reached target Default.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 10:50:31 kafka1 systemd[1673]: Startup finished in 47ms.
-- Subject: System start-up is now complete
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- All system services necessary queued for starting at boot have been
-- successfully started. Note that this does not mean that the machine is
-- now idle as services might still be busy with completing start-up.
-- 
-- Kernel start-up required KERNEL_USEC microseconds.
-- 
-- Initial RAM disk start-up required INITRD_USEC microseconds.
-- 
-- Userspace start-up required 47460 microseconds.
Dec 16 10:50:31 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1001.
-- Subject: Unit user@1001.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user@1001.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 16 10:50:37 kafka1 sudo[1763]:    kafka : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/kafka ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status kafka.service
Dec 16 10:50:37 kafka1 sudo[1763]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by kafka(uid=0)
Dec 16 10:50:37 kafka1 sudo[1763]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dec 16 10:59:18 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: 131.155.140.129 local addr 192.168.1.201 -> <null>
Dec 16 10:59:38 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: 5.79.108.34 local addr 192.168.1.201 -> <null>
Dec 16 10:59:54 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: 82.99.215.101 local addr 192.168.1.201 -> <null>
Dec 16 11:00:05 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: 91.189.91.157 local addr 192.168.1.201 -> <null>
Dec 16 11:00:24 kafka1 ntpd[1275]: 195.78.244.50 local addr 192.168.1.201 -> <null>
Dec 16 11:02:59 kafka1 sudo[2160]:    kafka : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/kafka ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Dec 16 11:02:59 kafka1 sudo[2160]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by kafka(uid=0)
```

Comment: Run it like this `kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.conf &` and see if systemd goes with that!

Comment: Hi and thanks, When I want to run Kafka manually I use the sign `&` and it gives me back the command. I tried it in `systemd` and it errors and doesn't support `&`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I updated the question!

Comment: Add `journalctl -xe` to your post too!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Done!

Comment: Is this part of that service `GeoIP City (IPv4) (type 2) DB not available`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen No, I don't think so. The Kafka process run after boot but after the `time-out` seconds it stops! I can manually issue the command `kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.conf &` and it runs correctly.